# Can we interrupt a thread which has acquired lock?

Tags: java, java-threads

As far as I know, `Lock` has a method `lockInterruptibly`, which can interrupt a thread which is polling to acquire a lock. So I wonder the case that when the thread has acquired the lock successfully and doing stuff inside `try` block, can it be interrupted? Why? If it can be, how?

Comment: Well, yes, by calling Thread.interrupt(). Whether the thread has acquired a lock or not is irrelevant: it doesn't change anything to the way you interrupt it, and to the way the thread must handle interruptions.

Comment: You might think about how to change your design so that no thread ever needs to hold a lock for so long that interrupts become an issue.  If a thread has to hold a lock for longer than it takes to assign a few values to a few fields, that's a sign of a design that's headed for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to be very careful to ensure that you release the lock if you do so.

This is a situation in Java where it would be really nice to have destructors that are guaranteed to be called when an object goes out of scope.

Thankfully you can get around that limitation with a `try ... finally` block. Your asynchronous code may look something like this:

```
class Foo implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Lock.lock();
        try
        {
            bar();
            if (Thread.isInterrupted()) return; // finally block will be called
            bar();
            if (Thread.isInterrupted()) return;
            bar();
        }
        finally
        {
            Lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP appears to be asking about `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`. If `Lock` is meant to be a variable of that type, then the method calls should be `Lock.lock()`, and `Lock.unlock()`.  Also, it would be more conventional for a variable's name to begin with a lower-case letter.

Comment: You might mention the reason why you put `Lock.acquire()` _before_ the `try`.  I've seen people write code where they acquire the lock inside the `try` block, which can cause problems if it is possible for the acquire method to throw an exception.

Comment: It was just a code sketch. I wasn't trying to represent any particular Lock implementation, but I've changed it anyway.